# What is the difference between Accord, Treaty, Agreement and Pact?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

In international affairs, some terms are frequently used. **What is the exact definition of these words?**

I have found that some people are using two or more terms to express same meaning. I've searched enough but did not find any satisfactory answer and my search only made me more confused.

The terms are given below:

- Treaty
- Agreement
- Accord
- Pact

  *Thanks in advance*

Comment: What is the difference ***between*** Accord, Treaty, Agreement and Pact? :)

Comment: The main thing is that "treaty" implies a formal, legally-binding agreement, while the others are a bit more squishy.

Comment: In such a question, you should include dictionary definitions.  And what you found unsatisfactory in them.

Comment: Dictionary definitions bears almost same meaning. That is why i asked here.

Answer (score -3):

You're right, the meanings are similar.

You can find the exact definitions in any good dictionary. Merriam Webster is one of the best, and you can find it online.

If you still need help after you've looked them up, come back and tell us why you're confused.

Your thanks is clearly in advance. Just *Thanks* does it. Thanks!